# DQL select all users and count the number of reservations of each

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, query-builder, dql

I'm trying to select all my users and, for each user, count the number of reservations made and incoming. For the moment I have this

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('user');
return $qb->select('user')
  ->leftJoin('user.reservations', 'reservations')
  ->leftJoin('reservations.marketDate', 'market_date')
  ->addSelect('COUNT(nb_reservations FROM reservations WHERE market_date.date >= CURRENT_DATE())')
  ->orderBy('user.name')
  ->groupBy('user.id')
  ->getQuery()
  ->getResult();
```

But I have this error

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 59 near 'market_date >=': Error: Class
>   'market_date' is not defined.

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('user');
return $qb->select('user, count(reservations) as count')
  ->leftJoin('user.reservations', 'reservations')
  ->leftJoin('reservations.marketDate', 'market_date')
  ->where('market_date.date >= CURRENT_DATE()')
  ->orderBy('user.name')
  ->groupBy('user.id')
  ->getQuery()
  ->getResult();
```

Comment: this solution selects users who have future reservations and counts future reservations of the user. I would like to select all users and count the number of future reservations even if there are 0

Comment: Then you need to use a left outer join instead.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in the *COUNT* does not seem correct: the COUNT should not include the whole statement. Try this:

```
->addSelect('COUNT(nb_reservations) FROM reservations WHERE market_date.date >= CURRENT_DATE()')
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried your solution but now I have this error `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 41 near 'reservations': Error: Class 'reservations' is not defined.`